# How to find the mode value of a list?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Is there a function in scala collections to find the max number of occurrence of a value in a list,

Lets say I have a list

```
L = List("A","B","B","E","B","E","B","B","C","E","B")

output: "B".
```

I can write a module to calculate this, but I would expect there should be a scala "way" or scala collection function to do this, already. Thanks!

Comment: It appears you have completely changed the question from asking about the mode, to asking about the number of occurrences of a value in the list.  Did you mean to open a new question?

Comment: No, I got the answer:) But, when I searched for mode of list, I couldn't find any results but there were ones for number of occurrences. I thought not everybody understands "StatSpeak" `mode`, so to get better visibility, I changed.I hope that is okay. If not, I can revert back.

Comment: Oh I see.  It's your question. :)  But I think "mode" is fine.  It's very precise.  The way the question reads now suggests that you only want the `groupBy` part of the solution.  You're question doesn't suggest anything about finding the element with the MAX number of occurrences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know of a ready-made way to do it, but this is how I would do it:

```
l.groupBy(i => i).mapValues(_.size).maxBy(_._2)._1
```

Oh, but note this doesn't handle the case where the mode is not unique!

Comment: A small modification will produce all modes. `val grouped = L.groupBy(x => x).mapValues(_.size)`, `val modeValue = grouped.maxBy(_._2)._2`, and `val modes = grouped.filter(_._2 == modeValue).map(_._1)`.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the mode:

```
import scala.collection.breakOut
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
def mode
  [T, CC[X] <: Seq[X]](coll: CC[T])
  (implicit o: T => Ordered[T], cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, T, CC[T]])
  : CC[T] = {
  val grouped = coll.groupBy(x => x).mapValues(_.size).toSeq
  val max = grouped.map(_._2).max
  grouped.filter(_._2 == max).map(_._1)(breakOut)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the modes of the list (without RDD):

```
val grouped = L.groupBy(i => i).map(kv => (kv._1, kv._2.size))
val modeValue = grouped.maxBy(_._2)._2
val modes = grouped.filter(kv => kv._2 == modeValue).map(_._1)
```