# How do I create an ordered list of [T, Int] in descending order for any orderable T?

Tags: scala, frequency

I looked at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21998521/how-to-find-the-mode-value-of-a-list) to see how to create a list of map items in descending order of the count those items occur in an original list.  I have to do this for a bunch of lists of different types: `String`, `Int`, `Short`, `Float`, `Byte`, ...

I could write:

```
def freqA(a: List[String]): ListMap[String, Int] =
  ListMap(a.groupBy(i => i).mapValues(_.size).toSeq.sortWith(_._2 > _._2):_*)

def freqB(a: List[Int]): ListMap[Int, Int] =
  ListMap(a.groupBy(i => i).mapValues(_.size).toSeq.sortWith(_._2 > _._2):_*)

...
```

but I just want to write this once using a type `T`.  I thought I remembered how to do this, but I'm blanking out.  I hope this is easy for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out.  Thank you Scala for not making it too hard on a Friday afternoon:

```
def freqB[T](a: List[T]): ListMap[T, Int] =
    ListMap[T, Int](a.groupBy(i => i).mapValues(_.size).toSeq.sortWith(_._2 > _._2):_*)
```